# Command "I'm" on linux ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command

I did type `I'm running` and then like if it was a program. I just want to know more about this command or program.

Answer (score 7):

The ' starts a shell quoting. The shell continues reading the "command" until this quoting is closed. You have to type a second `'`. After that <kbd>Enter</kbd> will not ask another line of input but (most probably) tell you that the "command" could not be found.